# Check if numpy array falls within bounds

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Looking for a more efficient way to check if items within a numpy array fall within any (or match at least once) of a set of min & max values. I toyed around with `any()` and `np.any()` and `all()` but these are newer concepts to me.

```
y_minmax_bounds = [[1.1, 2.0], [3.3, 6.21], [5.75, 10.0]]
y = np.array([1.5, 2.5, 2, 6, 8, 10])
withinbounds = [((y > min) & (y < max))for min, max in y_minmax_bounds]
print(withinbounds)
```

Returns:

```
[array([True, False, False, False, False, False]), 
array([False, False, False,  True, False, False]), 
array([False, False, False,  True,  True, False])]
```

After a array solution of:

```
[True False False True True False]
```

I can loop over `y_minmax_bounds`, but this seems inefficient given a very large np.array to check. The actual problem will also be enforcing this in multiple dimensions (`x_minmax_bounds` on x, `z_minmax_bounds` over z).

Comment: Only 10 doesn't fall between at least one interval.

Comment: Apologies - I have edited a typo in `y_minmax_bounds`, which also sets 2.5 and 2 as False.

Comment: The solution should still work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Numpy broadcasting

```
mn, mx = np.array(y_minmax_bounds).T
x = y[:, None]

((x > mn) & (x < mx)).any(1)

array([ True, False, False,  True,  True, False])
```